# XGBoost tree dump contains lots of empty trees

Tags: interpretation, cart, boosting

After fitting a regression model using XGBoost, I want to inspect the individual trees that were built. In the resulting table, I find a lot of 0-depth trees, i.e. trees with only a leaf node, and mostly NA values in columns "Split", "Yes", "No", "Missing" while a constant value for column "Quality" == 0.07 and a different value for Cover for each 0-tree. How do I interpret these lines? And how come they add value? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example for what you describe? It could be hypothesised that what is observed is a phenomenon where missing values are assigned some offset values but without some more information it is really hard to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: a reprex

xgb_bin_data <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(mtcars[,-9]), label = mtcars$am)

xgb_bin_fit <- xgb.train(params =list(max_depth = 2, silent = 1, objective = "binary:logistic", base_score = 0.5), data = xgb_bin_data, nrounds = 50)

xgb_dump_text_with_stats <- xgb.dump(xgb_bin_fit, dump_format = "text", with_stats = TRUE)